# Bootstrap select not working after Laravel livewire render

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a [Bootstrap selectpicker](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) element that works fine on the first render. It's initialized with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').selectpicker();
});
```

But after livewire's render function is called the `<select>` element is not rendered as Bootstrap selectpicker anymore.

Going through both the docs (relevant sections [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/lifecycle-hooks) and [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrender)), I figured that the code below should fix it:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("livewire:load", function(event) {
        window.livewire.hook('afterDomUpdate', () => {
            $('select').selectpicker('refresh');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

and

```
$('select').selectpicker('render');
```

both within `afterDomUpdate`, that doesn't work as well. If I call all these functions from the console the DOM doesn't update the `<select>` element, so indeed these functions do not seem to work.

Comment: I have the same issue like this, but my case is when using the select2 plugin

Comment: Same here, been losing hours with this

Answer (score 9):

in case anyone else gets stuck with this here is how you do it.

```
<div wire:ignore id="for-bootstrap-select">
     <select class="form-control" data-container="#for-bootstrap-select">
         @foreach($data as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
         @endforeach
     </select>
</div>
```

**Reason** [from the creator of livewire himself: Caleb!](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/45#issuecomment-513228288)

Comment: You put this in the livewire blade file...but do you also require jquery in the app.js and import the css in the app.scss? i´m using mix?

Comment: Yes. Since my livewire component extends the master layout and all the assets (js/css) are initialized in master. I’m using cdns and not local hosted libraries but even if you are using mix im sure its not gonna affect anything.

Comment: Hi BezhanSalleh, it simply doesn´t render, unless with a class form-control, but if i try to use select multiple with multiple data-actions-box="true" which is what i want, it just shows a open select with all the options. Could you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542114/livewire-bootstrap-select-not-rendering . Regards.

Comment: @Japa check it out... i hope it helps... if it doesn't you need to post the actual code snippets so i could give it a look... because in my test it works perfectly... also posted the link for playground where you can check it.

Comment: Hi BenzhanSalleh, first of all thank you very much for spending time helping me, i´m going to check it out and test and i´ll give the feedback, Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `wire:ignore` on your html `input/select` tag

Answer (score 1):

If some one still seeking form answer. adding wire:ignore is a bad idea, because then you cannot dynamicly change options, for example having select country, and then dynamicly change select city according to country. To get rid of wir:ignore, you can use this out side your component.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    Livewire.hook('message.received', (message, component) => {
        $('select').selectpicker('destroy');
    })
});

window.addEventListener('contentChanged', event => {
    $('select').selectpicker();
});</script>
```

and

```
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('contentChanged');
```

on your component.

selectpicker cannot be rendered on the same select, that why 'refresh' or 'render' doesn`t work even in console. You need to destroy it firest.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are reinitializing your selectpicker everytime you update the dom. that is why whenever you are using

```
 $('select').selectpicker('refresh');
```

inside your livewire hook, its basically refreshing the fresh initialized selectpicker in your dom. I'm guessing it, because as per your code and statement above it should work unless behind the scene something wrong happen like I mentioned.

I dont know if I make sense. please check either you are reinitializing it before refreshing. let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

I know this is practically the same as yours but in my case, not all selects were bootstrap-selects, so targeting just the class of .selectpicker seemed to have the desired effect. Could be a red herring, but worked for me.

Comment: How is this different from using `'select'`? I understand you now use a class instead of the element type, but the function called `refresh` is still the same?

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

it must be work

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    console.log('start'); $('select').selectpicker();
})
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Livewire.hook('element.updating', (fromEl, toEl, component) => {
        console.log('being update'); $('select').selectpicker('destroy'); })
        Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => { console.log('processed'); $('select').selectpicker();
    }) 
});
```