# Livewire - Bootstrap select not rendering

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I´m struglling for hours on this, i just can´t seem to put the bootstrap-select working inside a livewire component, so i´ll try to be specific on my scenario and hopping someone could help me. I have a laravel project using [this](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE) adminlte, so my code is:

**web.php**

```
Route::livewire('/new','new')->layout('adminlte::page');
```

Then, i have my **page A** where i´m including the livewire component which by the way it´s a bootstrap modal.

```
@livewire('new')
```

Inside my app.scss i have:(i installed the bootstrap select with npm)

```
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap-select/sass/bootstrap-select.scss';
```

And inside my app.js i have:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select');
```

After this, i went to my livewire blade file and tried to use the example 'Select/deselect all options:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

but nothing happens, so i discovered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677433/bootstrap-select-not-working-after-laravel-livewire-render) link and used the solution that is given but the result is the same.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? i just don´t know what am i missing, i also tried other links but if i put everything here it´s gonna be a long question.

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted here the problem is not quite clear. with the snippets you posted we cant really track where the issue is. it's always best to include the minimal code to reproduce the issue so we could easily find a solution for you and others who might stumble upon it. but i'm gonna give it a go and answer your question anyways.

some blade file with necessary libraries loaded **welcome.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Open Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
// 
<div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true close-btn">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               <!-- livewire component -->
              <livewire:bootstrap-select-multiple />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    @livewireScripts
    <script>
      $(function () {
          $('select').selectpicker();
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Livewire Component Class: BootstrapSelectMultiple.php**

```
<?php

use Livewire\Component;

class BootstrapSelectMultiple extends Component
{
    public $customers = [];
  
    public function render()
    {
        return view('bootstrap-select-multiple');
    }
}
```

**Livewire Component View: bootstrap-select-multiple.blade.php**

```
<div>
  <div class="" wire:ignore id="for-customers">
    <select class="form-control show-tick" data-style="btn-primary" title="Select Customer..." multiple wire:model="customers" data-container="#for-customers" data-actions-box="true">
      <option  value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
      <option  value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
      <option  value="John Wick">John Wick</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <hr>

  Customers List<br>
  <ul>
  @forelse($customers as $key => $value)
    <li>{{$value}}</li><br>
  @empty 
    Currently there are no selected customers.
  @endforelse 
  </ul>

</div>
```

Playaround updated as well [BootstrapSelectMultiple](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/30ff56e8-1bd4-4c92-86d7-bd5b92d9516ahttps://) and see it in action.

Comment: Hi BezhanSalleh, i have discouvered the source of my problem.The thing is, my livewire component is a bootstrap modal that is called from a view, when you click a button the modal appears(and this modal is the livewire component). So i tested it in this "mother" view and the bootsratselect apeared currectly, but inside the modal it does not. Funny thing is, all my blade file @extends('adminlte::page'), so my livewire route has ->layout('adminlte::page');...why does it not appear in the modal? regards

Comment: @Japa i have updated the answer based on your comment. now the livewire component is inside the bootstrap modal and also the playground is update so you could see it in action.